# Not getting email address of windows logged in user in offline mode in vb .net

Tags: vb.net-2010

We have a  vb .net code for getting email addres of windows logged in user.
the code we have is as below :-

**System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress()**

This code works fine in online mode that is when connected to internet.
But it does not retrieve email address of windows logged in user in offline mode (when not connected to internet)

Please sugesst some solution.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Windows logged in user's email when offline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257589/get-windows-logged-in-users-email-when-offline)

Comment: Any workaround to get email address of logged in user in offline mode using vb .net

Comment: The linked question provided a workaround. Not a great one, but a one.